# testng-failed.xml is not creating when we execute the build using jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, testng

when we execute the selenium scripts using testng.xml file in jenkin server. we are not able to view the testng-failed.xml file . Could you please help us to understand why it is not showing the file . when we execute same build using eclipse id we are able to view it but it is not creating when we execute using jenkins

Comment: @vijaykumar j did you add TestNg result plugins in your Jenkins ?

Comment: Hi Dhru , I think I did not add it